# User exists, but not returned in search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We have an odd situation where a user exists, but when we search for their first name, matching the exact spelling and casing, no results are returned.

[image]

[image]

Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Presuming "name" is a computed field, is it possible the user's first name is actually " John" (with a space at the start) that's stripped from the computed value?

Comment: So, get this. If I search `John ` (space at the end) I get all the John's being returned... That must be a bug, right? Especially as it only happens for Johns. Daves are fine..